# How to use spring boot in gradle without the spring boot gradle plugin

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

Can anyone show me or point me to a spring boot gradle project that does not make use of the spring boot gradle plugin.

I'm looking for something like a spring boot starter web hello world example that doesn't use the gradle plugin.

I can't imagine that the plugin is a requirement, but a search for examples all seem to lean on the gradle plugin, which lets just say is not an option in my environment, and no I can't switch to maven either.

Ideally the gradle build would work by adding something like the following:

**gradle.properties**

```
springBootVersion=2.1.3.RELEASE
```

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
   compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: springBootVersion

}
```

Comment: You're right that the plugin isn't, strictly speaking, a requirement. Exactly what the alternative should look like will depend on what you want your Gradle build to be able to do. Can you describe your requirements in more detail?

Comment: Updated the question with an excerpt of the target gradle dependencies section.

Comment: It appears that actually works. Are there gotchas to this approach that I am missing?

Comment: It's hard to know what will be a gotcha for you. By not using Boot's Gradle plugin you'll miss out on all of the functionality [described in its documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.3.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/). Only you can decide if any of that will be a problem or if you're prepared to find or implement alternatives for the parts you'd like to use.

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution. without the plugin, there's no target to create a single jar. Our problem with the plugin is that we have an old app on boot 1 and we're stuck with the old plugin that only works with old gradle and because of this we cannot even update intellij, which needs the new gradle. So it is a dependency hell this way.

Answer (score 1):

I used the spring dependency management plugin, and it works

```
buildscript {
 ext {
        springDepManagementVersion = '1.0.10.RELEASE'
        springBootVersion = '2.6.6'
        springCloudVersion = "2021.0.1"
  }

dependencies {
        classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:${springDepManagementVersion}"
        
    }
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
        mavenBom "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${springBootVersion}"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth"
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    ...
}
```

I can't use spring boot gradle plugin, since I can only use gradle 6.7.1, while spring boot gradle plugin requires gradle version at least 6.8 to support spring boot 2.6. I was inspired by the spring cloud bom solution.